# How do you sum and combine a string

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

How can I get:

```
  pn     | min max
  ------ | ------
  ABC123 | 0,0
  ABC123 | 1,1
  ABC123 | 1,1
  ABC123 | 1,1
```

To:

```
  pn     | min max
  ------ | -------
  ABC123 | 3,3
```

- Oracle database 11g
- PL/SQL 11.2.4.0

This is what I have now:

```sql
SELECT
   PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.PN,
   PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.MAXIMUM_STOCK || ',' || PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.MINIMUM_STOCK AS MIN_MAX
FROM
   PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL
WHERE ("PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL"."PN" = :PN)
```

Comment: You have a column with comma separated values?

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, and `SUM()`. BTW, why store numbers as strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
 SELECT
               PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.PN,
               Sum(PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.MAXIMUM_STOCK) || ',' || sum(PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.MINIMUM_STOCK) AS MIN_MAX
    FROM
               PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL
    WHERE ("PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL"."PN" = :PN)
group by PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL.PN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT pn, SUM(min) as min, SUM(max) as max FROM PN_INVENTORY_LEVEL GROUP BY pn
```

Comment: This works, but the result segregates into two separate columns

Answer (score 0):

I believe that would be the answer for you question if you have `min_max` in one column as a string (replace `tab` with ***your-table-name***):

```
WITH
tab1 AS(
SELECT t.pn,
       t.min_max,
       INSTR(t.min_max, ',',1) POS
FROM tab t
),
tab3 AS 
(
SELECT tt.pn,
       SUBSTR(tt.min_max, 1,tt.pos-1) st,
       SUBSTR(tt.min_max,tt.pos+1,LENGTH(tt.min_max)-tt.pos) nd
FROM tab1 tt
)
SELECT ttt.pn,
       SUM(ttt.st) || ',' || SUM(ttt.nd) min_max
FROM tab3 ttt
GROUP BY ttt.pn
```

it gives me the result:

```
1   ABC123  3,3
```

Comment: Thanks v.much, however below helped me get the result needed.